# Heroku ошибка 400 при запросе от серверов Telegram

Tags: telegram-bot, api, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Написал обработчик для телеграм-бота на `Ruby on Rails` и выложил на Heroku.

Если отправлять запросы вручную то все работает отлично, а если запрос приходит от Telegram, то выдает ошибку

> ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError (wrong number of
> arguments (given 2, expected 1))

Полный лог:

```
2021-05-11T11:38:49.026985+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-05-11T11:38:49.026873 #4]  INFO -- : [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] Started POST "/api/telegramHandler/oTh3r_$lD3" for 91.108.6.131 at 2021-05-11 11:38:49 +0000
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028675+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2021-05-11T11:38:49.028585 #4] FATAL -- : [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b]
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028676+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)):
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028677+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b]
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028678+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:96:in `rescue in parse_formatted_parameters'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028678+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:92:in `parse_formatted_parameters'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028683+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:399:in `block in POST'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028683+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/request.rb:69:in `fetch'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028683+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/request.rb:69:in `fetch_header'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028686+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:398:in `POST'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028687+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:55:in `parameters'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028688+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:284:in `_wrapper_enabled?'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028688+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028689+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] activerecord (6.1.3.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028689+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:165:in `process'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028689+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028690+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028690+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028690+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028691+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028691+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028691+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028692+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:842:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028692+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028693+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028693+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028694+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028694+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028694+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028695+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028695+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028695+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028696+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] railties (6.1.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028696+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] railties (6.1.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028696+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028697+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028697+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028703+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] railties (6.1.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028704+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028704+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028705+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028705+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028706+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028706+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:24:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028706+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028707+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:92:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028707+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] railties (6.1.3.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028708+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] puma (5.3.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:249:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028708+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] puma (5.3.0) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `block in handle_request'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028708+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] puma (5.3.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:338:in `with_force_shutdown'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028709+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] puma (5.3.0) lib/puma/request.rb:75:in `handle_request'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028709+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] puma (5.3.0) lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
2021-05-11T11:38:49.028710+00:00 app[web.1]: [4ccb26fc-8ca3-4cc5-969e-1d549c241d9b] puma (5.3.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:145:in `block in spawn_thread'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.050968+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-05-11T11:39:49.050864 #4]  INFO -- : [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] Started POST "/api/telegramHandler/oTh3r_$lD3" for 91.108.6.131 at 2021-05-11 11:39:49 +0000
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052181+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2021-05-11T11:39:49.052094 #4] FATAL -- : [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee]
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052183+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)):
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052184+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee]
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052184+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:96:in `rescue in parse_formatted_parameters'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052185+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:92:in `parse_formatted_parameters'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052186+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:399:in `block in POST'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052186+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/request.rb:69:in `fetch'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052187+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/request.rb:69:in `fetch_header'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052188+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:398:in `POST'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052188+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:55:in `parameters'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052189+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:284:in `_wrapper_enabled?'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052189+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052190+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] activerecord (6.1.3.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052190+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:165:in `process'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052191+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052191+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052192+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052192+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052193+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052193+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052193+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052194+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:842:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052195+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052195+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052196+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052196+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052197+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052197+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052198+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052198+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052198+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052199+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] railties (6.1.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052199+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] railties (6.1.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052199+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052200+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052200+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052205+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] railties (6.1.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052206+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052206+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052206+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052207+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052207+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052207+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:24:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052208+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052208+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:92:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052208+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] railties (6.1.3.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052209+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] puma (5.3.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:249:in `call'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052209+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] puma (5.3.0) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `block in handle_request'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052210+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] puma (5.3.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:338:in `with_force_shutdown'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052210+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] puma (5.3.0) lib/puma/request.rb:75:in `handle_request'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052210+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] puma (5.3.0) lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.052211+00:00 app[web.1]: [3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee] puma (5.3.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:145:in `block in spawn_thread'
2021-05-11T11:39:49.054653+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/telegramHandler/oTh3r_$lD3" host=webgram-api.herokuapp.com request_id=3fd22eea-0aa5-443b-813f-88a6e7e17aee fwd="91.108.6.131" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=400 bytes=179 protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

В запросе телеграма были слишком длинные хэдеры и хероку их банил. Я сделал на php на дешевом хостинге редирект - принимал вебхук и отправлял чистые данные без хэдеров в приложение на хероку.